# How do I set Google Latitude to auto-update with location regularly?

Tags: gps, google-maps, geolocation, google-latitude

When I use Google Maps it sets my Google Latitude location, but once I turn Maps off it stops. I'd like it to update with my location on a regular basis. I don't want to drain the battery by always using the GPS, but it'd be nice if it updated, say, every half hour or so.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found [this](http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Google%20Mobile/thread?tid=00fd6e74b895ef95&hl=en) from the Google Mobile Help forum after a little searching. It's from 8/15/09 so I actually see something a little different on my phone Settings > Location > Google Location Services. I haven't tested it but hope it helps.

Quoting the site:

> Hi everyone, Apologies for not
>   updating this thread specifically
>   sooner. There is a new version
>   available in Android Market (version
>   3.1.2). Just search for "Google Maps" if you have at least the 1.5 system
>   update (Cupcake) and install this over
>   your current version of Maps.
>
> Please let me know if you experience
>   background location updating issues
>   with this version. As long as you have
>   enabled automatic location detection
>   in the Latitude privacy menu and have
>   enabled location detection (Settings >
>   Security & location > Use wireless
>   networks), Latitude should update your
>   location while your phone is on. This
>   means your location should never
>   appear older than ~1 hour to any of
>   your friends.
>
> Thank you all for your patience! Chris

Answer (score 2):

Using [Latify](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.ecs.latify), you can configure location updates using a specific interval. It will syncup with Google Latitude using either GPS or WIFI at the defined interval, even when the application is not running.

Comment: Just downloaded Latify - looks really neat!

Answer (score 1):

Check out [Backitude](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=gaugler.backitude). It takes over the Latitude updating for you. Good reviews.