# How do I configure Google Latitude to auto-update with location regularly on a Motorola Droid?

Tags: settings, motorola-droid, gps, google-latitude

On the surface, this is same question as [this question](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/434/how-do-i-set-google-latitude-to-auto-update-with-location-regularly), but I've made the changes according to that question's accepted answer and I still cannot get latitude to auto-update unless I have an app using GPS open.

If I fire up Google maps or MyTracks, a location is sent.  but once I close or switch to a new application, my location no longer transmits.  It has been like this for several weeks.

My Android version is 2.2.1.   GPS is on, but the GPS icon doesn't appear until I start an app that uses GPS.

I actually seem to remember that being a requested feature for an earlier version of android (1.something).

Am I missing something else?

More data: Google maps version <strike>4.5.0 (#4519)</strike> 5.0 (http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TAh4yiCzgKw I guess I'll need to retest and see if I still have the issue)

Comment: You know that you can just post the full address here, there's no need to use a URL shortening service, particularly when you send people straight to a video with no warning.

Comment: sorry...you're right.  youtube is blocked where i work and i hate it when people do that to me.  link replaced.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My issue was resolved by upgrading Google Maps to v5.0.

For those troubleshooting this issue, also see this question (which should probably be your first step):   [How do I set Google Latitude to auto-update with location regularly?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/434/how-do-i-set-google-latitude-to-auto-update-with-location-regularly)